# How to sum column in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

How do I calculate the sum of a column in Crystal Reports?

For example:

```
[No] [Name] [value]
 1    a      2
 1    a      3
 1    a      5
 1    a      4
 2    b      1
 2    b      2
 3    c      10
```

I want to display like this:

```
[No] [Name] [Value]
 1    a      14
 2    b      3
 3    c      10
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that you would have to (assuming that the value column is numeric):

- Add all 3 columns to your report
- add a grouping for [no] and [name]
- click on the [value] field (on the report) and click the summary button

  - select sum for 'calculate this summary'
  - for ease, check off 'add to all group levels'
- Copy or drag the columns automatically created in header #1 & header #2 to footer #2
- suppress sections group header #1, header #2, detail and footer #2

This should give you what you're looking for.  Let us know how you make out.